# Mercurial: after replacing a file with its temp backup copy, my folder now shows a red exclamation mark

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

In a folder, I copied a file as a backup.  I made a change to the original file, and tested something out.  I then deleted the current file, and move my backup over to go back to how things were.  All the files have green check marks on them in the folder, but the folder itself has a red exclamation mark.  I didn’t run any hg commands while doing this.  The timestamp of the file is probably different even though the content is the same.

How can I make the red exclamation mark go away?

I did try to run hg revert on the file, but it says no changes needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red exclamation mark on my folder went away after I did a hg update --clean.  But that also reverted all the changes I had going.  At least that is one way to get the folder state and folder icon to re-synchronize properly.

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens to you again: Realize that the exclamation mark comes from the tortoisehg Windows integration, not from mercurial itself. If you see odd behavior, try opening a command prompt (tortoisehg will open one for you with `Repository > Terminal`) and typing `hg status`. If hg does not report modifications, the problem is in the browser; so try refreshing Explorer or whatever.

Comment: When I did hg status, it did not report modifications, and refreshing the Explorer does not clear away the Red Exclamation mark, that is why I posted the question.  The solution I posted above to do a hg update --clean and then a refresh of the explorer was how I was able to clear it.

Comment: Well, throwing out your unchecked mods is no solution if you ask me. But never mind-- since you've resolved the problem, there's no telling what caused it anymore.